# TSFRESH: Get N most relevant features

Tags: tsfresh

Is there any way to get the N most relevant features in TSFRESH? Currently, the method extract_relevant_features has a parameter fdr_level, but for a big amount of time series (>1000), the function with a very low fdr_level parameter (< 0.01) returns more than 400 features. I would like to return the 20 or 40 most relevant features.

Comment: See also this similar question and answer: [Selecting only a certain number of top features using tsfresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204734/selecting-only-a-certain-number-of-top-features-using-tsfresh)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `calculate_relevance_table` ([link to the docu](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tsfresh.feature_selection.html#tsfresh.feature_selection.relevance.calculate_relevance_table)) (which is called internally in the `select_features` method, which in turn is called in the `extract_relevant_features` method) to get the p-value for each of the features and then only use the TOP-N sorted by p-value.
So the general flow would be:

- extract all features with `extract_features`
- call `calculate_relevance_table`
- sort by p-value
- get only the top N

You could even tell `tsfresh` the next time to only extract those features (to save a lot of computation time) following [this](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/feature_extraction_settings.html#a-handy-trick-do-i-really-have-to-create-the-dictionary-by-hand).