# Selecting only a certain number of top features using tsfresh

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction, feature-selection, tsfresh

How can I select top n features of time series using tsfresh? Can I decide the number of top features I want to extract?

Comment: Did you already solve it? If not, what did you try so far?

Comment: @flyingdutchman my approach to this was to calculate the relevance table using the tsfresh.feature_selection.relevance module.  It gave a list of relevant features that are calculated using the Benjamini Hochberg procedure which is a multiple testing procedure that decides which features to keep and which to cut off (solely based on the p-values). I took the features are the top as the most relevant features. 

You can refer to the following link:

https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tsfresh.feature_selection.html#

Comment: Ah, good to know, this is the same what I did for my problem. I will just put this as an answer, so that this question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the above comment from @Chaitra and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991201/tsfresh-get-n-most-relevant-features) I give an answer.

You can decide the number of top features by using the `tsfresh` relevance table described in the [documentation](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tsfresh.feature_selection.html#module-tsfresh.feature_selection.relevance). You can then sort the table by the p-value and the the top `n` features.

Example code printing top 11 features:

```py
from tsfresh import extract_features
from tsfresh.feature_selection.relevance import calculate_relevance_table

extracted_features = extract_features(
    X,
    column_id="id",
    column_kind="kind",
    column_value="value",
)
relevance_table = calculate_relevance_table(extracted_features, y)
relevance_table = relevance_table[relevance_table.relevant]
relevance_table.sort_values("p_value", inplace=True)
print(relevance_table["feature"][:11])
```